# Removing unphysical solutions of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

I am solving differential equations in a physical context and I would like to remove 'unphysical solutions'. In my case, these correspond to non-polynomial solutions. My program outputs general solutions such as:

```
((-2 + 2 del + x) C[1])/(-1 + 2 del) + 
C[2]/(4 (-1 + del)^2 (-1 + 2 del)) 
AppellF1[-(3/2), -del, -(3/2) + del, -(1/2),(2 (-1 + del))/(-2 + 2 del + x), (-3 + 2 del)/(-2 + 2 del + x)]
```

Here, we get a physical solution (polynomial in $x$) by setting `C[2] := 0`. I have tried using replacement rules such as `solution /. AppellF1[args__] -> 0`, but many different pathological functions (such as unevaluated integrals, hypergeometric functions, etc.) come up, and I have little hope of identifying all of them. Thus, I would like a more general way to proceed. Note that it is not clear what the boundary conditions for the problem should be, and so it is impossible to use them to fix the constants.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `PolynomialQ[expression,x]` to test them, which will see if your overall solution is a polynomial, or, if you have a list of solutions `sols`, then you could use:

```
Select[sols, PolynomialQ[#, x] &]
```

If your solution, `sol` has a number of coefficients, for instance `c1`, `c2` and `c3` which are free parameters, then you can at least check term by term:

```
PolynomialQ[(sol /. (# -> 0 & /@ DeleteCases[{c1, c2, c3}, #])), 
   x] & /@ {c1, c2, c3}
```

This creates a list of the different possibilities of sol with all but one of the c's set to 0, then asks if each of these is a polynomial.